# 3D rotation and movement of ball on a 2D plane

Tags: 2d, 3d, animation, graphics-programming

Here is a video of Amiga arcade pool game:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTQIPFBUFIg 
I am making a similar game with C and Gtk+3.0 but I don't know how to show balls 3D movement on 2D plane!
I guess there is some tricks with changing image of the ball but I don't know exactly what to do.
I can move the balls on 2D plane but I can't show their rotation!
how did they show 3D movement of ball in Amiga's pool game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of effect is commonly done by creating a sprite sheet with the various angles pre-rendered. Then the game switches between the various sprites depending on what the angle of the ball is.